# Matlab on Mountain Lion not working -

Tags: matlab, x11, osx-mountain-lion, dyld

Matlab (R2010a) seems to be kaput on Mountain Lion - if I click on the icon it crashes immediately.

I installed XQuartz and Java on Mountain Lion but still keep getting the following error when trying to open it from xterm:

```
bash-3.2$ /Applications/MATLAB_R2010a.app/bin/matlab
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libXext.6.dylib
Referenced from:   /Applications/MATLAB_R2010a.app/bin/maci64/MATLAB.app/Contents/MacOS/libmwhg.dylib
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Unfortunately the error doesn't go away even after setting the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH variable as instructed in the blog post: http://quantumtunnel.wordpress.com/2012/07/29/matlab-for-mac-in-mountain-lion-without-x11/

```
bash-3.2$ export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Libraries
```

Can anybody please help?

P.S. I have already upgraded to Xcode 4.4 if that helps...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Somebody told me to re-install XQuartz and while searching for how to reinstall it, I figured that XQuartz is installed in /opt/X11/ as opposed to /usr/X11/ where the latter is the one that Matlab is looking for. So I resolved the problem by simply making a softlink:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/X11/ /usr/X11
```

Answer (score 0):

this work for me!

1. Install XQuartz
2. Launch XQuartz and from the menu launch an xterm.

Type the following command first:
$MATLAB/bin/matlab -maci

for me $MATLAB is /Applications/MATLAB_R2008b.app/ , is your app path.

source : http://quantumtunnel.wordpress.com/2012/07/29/matlab-for-mac-in-mountain-lion-without-x11/

Good Luck.